# event.preventDefault() or return false don't work in IE9

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, internet-explorer-9

I'm trying to get the following code to work in all versions of IE, as it works find in other browsers:

```
  <a href="" class="specificClass">Click Me </a>
    //Javascript
     $(".specificClass").click(
                        function(e) {
                            e.preventDefault();
                           // Do Something
                             //return false; Doesn't work either
                        }
                );
```

Switching to `href="#"` makes it try to go to the top of the page, again only in IE9. For example:
Leaving `href=""` redirects to the current link itself in IE9.

```
<a href="#" onclick="doSomething(this); return false;"> Click Me Two </a>
```

It seems like both approaches triggers the onclick Javascript to be called, but the default behavior for `href=""` is not getting overridden. If I use `event.preventDefault()` nothing happens.

The below approach works:

```
<a href="javascript:doSomething(this);"> Click Me Two </a>
function doSomething(me) {

    // event.preventDefault is not needed as the javascript is added via href

}
```

However I don't want to have href="javascript:" or onclick ="doSomething"for all my anchor tags **just to get it to work in IE9**. 
I also don't want to use a different tag (tried the span tag for example) since it is tricky to style up in all browsers.

Any other ideas?

Looks like it is a legit bug, I have submitted a request to fix it. I have also put in a workaround for now: 
https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/812247/event-preventdefault-or-return-false-dont-work-in-ie9

Comment: I see jQuery in your code - Note jQuery events and normal DOM events are different, does preventDefault not work even within jQuery?

Comment: And it does of course work in all other browsers ?

Comment: Just for the record, in your actual page the first above JS is in a script tag and below the link - correct?

Comment: Yes, The code is in a Javascript file and there is JQuery included as a library. preventDefault is not working even within the JQuery format, though it seems like it is triggered (added a debug point using the developer tools). My code is just an example to show what's happening. @adeneo Of course :)

Comment: if it helps, the HTML is generated via ASP code. Maybe something's going on there that doesn't add the .click trigger in JQuery in time on clicking?

Comment: I have submitted feedback to the IE team, let's hope we have a workaround soon https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/812247/event-preventdefault-or-return-false-dont-work-in-ie9

Comment: @Amy create a short self contained example somewhere - possibly on http://jsfiddle.net that illustrates your issue.

Comment: it seems to be working here: http://jsfiddle.net/4hfjq/10/  but not in the actual website. thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In IE9 the legacy event handler model is still partial used. `preventDefault()` works only, when the event listener is attached using `addEventListener()`.

If you want to prevent default action from an inline handler, you have to use the legacy method:

```
event.returnValue = false;
event.cancelBubble = true; // This is affects like event.stopPropagation() in older IEs
```

Though jQuery not working is odd, I've no explanation for that... Unless you're running IE in compatible mode and use jQuery 2.X?

---

**EDIT**

Also a reference to `console` object will break the code in IE<10, if Dev Tools are not opened. You can find a lot of fixes for this problem at SO. My favorite is this:

```
// The very first lines in the global context
if (!window.console) {
    window.console = {
        log: function () {}
        // Add other console methods, if the scripts on the page are using them
    }
}
```

Though the `console` problem can be avoided with the code above, it's always better to remove all loggings from the final code to be published.

Comment: Given his post content - this fixing the issue would surprise me since he uses jQuery which already normalizes this.

Comment: Hmm.. Looks like I've messed up things here... Maybe I'll wait OP's response, since I've not IE9 at hands right now. Though I can see an inline `onclick()` in the post too...

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Unfortunately this is also not working unless I have the Debugger open in IE, and it does seem to trigger. Is it possible the default behavior gets called even before the .click can be applied via JQuery. I'm using JQuery 1.8, can't control which version we're in.

Comment: @Amy After your comment, it looks like you've a `console.log()` in your handler function. IE9 doesn't recognize `console` if it's not open. Just remove/comment out the `console` calls, and your jQuery should work fine.

Comment: Just checked, no console.log in the handler function. Not sure what else it could be other than the default behavior handled faster than the onclick handler itself!

Comment: "`not working unless I have the Debugger open in IE`" clearly points to a reference to the `console` object, which is `undefined` in IE<10, if Dev tools are not opened... I'm sorry, looks like I can't figure out what's wrong with your code :-(. (5) In general, jQuery's "event model" works fine in IE9, and `onclick` is definetely handled before `href`.

Comment: If you can edit your answer a bit I'd like to mark it as the resolution - it had to with console.logs defined randomly across code. However, I have posted a resolution.

Comment: @Amy Actually I tried to add an edit to my answer for a couple of hours ago, but there was something wrong with my connection... Anyway, the answer is edited now.

Answer (score 1):

For IE9, if there is any console.log anywhere on the site, there will be unexpected behavior unless you have the developer tools open. Improbable for an actual user.

See how it works fine without any console.log (in IE9): jsfiddle.net/4hfjq/10, but not when you do: jsfiddle.net/4hfjq/20 tries to re-direct to "" page, unless you have the developer tool open.

In my case, there were just too many console.logs and so I go with another workaround, i.e. Use
`<a href="javascript:doSomething()">Link </a>` and define that code without using JQuery .eventType approach. Check this: jsfiddle.net/4hfjq/22

Answer (score 0):

This could be due to event bubbling.

See this link:
http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/

```
event.stopPropagation();
```

Comment: This would also really surprise me since his first sample of code does `return false` (below doesn't work either) which does both stopPropagation() and preventDefault()